# How to iterate over tuples using jax.lax.scan

Tags: python, jax

I am looking to translate a bit of code from a NumPy version listed here, to a [JAX](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) compatible version. The NumPy code iteratively calculates the value of a matrix, E from the values of other matrices, A, B, D, as well as the value of E from the previous iteration: E_jm1.

Both the NumPy and JAX version work in their listed forms and produce identical results. How can I get the JAX version to work when passing `A`, `B`, `D` as a tuple instead of as a concatenated array? I have a specific use case where a tuple would be more useful.

I found a [question asking something similar](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/763), but it just confirmed that this should be possible. There are no examples in the documentation or elsewhere that I could find.

Original NumPy version

```py
import numpy as np
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

def BAND_J(A, B, D, E_jm1):
    '''
        output: E(N x N)
        input: A(N x N), B(N x N), D(N x N), E_jm1(N x N)
        ⱼ = -[ + ⱼ₋₁]⁻¹ 
    '''

    B_inv = np.linalg.inv(B + np.dot( A, E_jm1 ))

    E  = -np.dot(B_inv, D)

    return E

key = jax.random.PRNGKey(0)

N  = 2
NJ = 4

# initialize matrices with random values
A, B, D = [ jax.random.normal(key, shape=(N,N,NJ)),
            jax.random.normal(key, shape=(N,N,NJ)),
            jax.random.normal(key, shape=(N,N,NJ)) ]
A_np, B_np, D_np = [np.asarray(A), np.asarray(B), np.asarray(D)]

# initialize E_0
E_0 = jax.random.normal(key+2, shape=(N,N))

E_np        = np.empty((N,N,NJ))
E_np[:,:,0] = np.asarray(E_0)

# iteratively calculate E from A, B, D, and ⱼ₋₁
for j in range(1,NJ):
    E_jm1       = E_np[:,:,j-1]
    E_np[:,:,j] = BAND_J(A_np[:,:,j], B_np[:,:,j], D_np[:,:,j], E_jm1)
```

JAX scan version

```py
def BAND_J(E, ABD):
    '''
        output: E(N x N)
        input: A(N x N), B(N x N), D(N x N), E_jm1(N x N)
    '''

    A, B, D = ABD

    B_inv = jnp.linalg.inv(B + jnp.dot( A, E ))

    E  = -jnp.dot(B_inv, D)

    return E, E # ("carryover", "accumulated")

abd = jnp.asarray([(A[:,:,j], B[:,:,j], D[:,:,j]) for j in range(NJ)])
# abd = tuple([(A[:,:,j], B[:,:,j], D[:,:,j]) for j in range(NJ)]) # this produces error
# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

_, E = lax.scan(BAND_J, E_0, abd)

for j in range(1, NJ):
    print(np.isclose(E[j-1], E_np[:,:,j]))
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "you can't". By design, `jax.scan` can scan over axes of arrays, not entries of arbitrary Python collections.

So if you want to use `scan`, you'll have to stack your entires into an array.

That said, since your tuple only has three elements, a good alternative would be to skip the scan and simply JIT-compile the `for` loop approach. JAX tracing will effectively unroll the loop and optimize the flattened sequence of operations. While this can lead to long compile times for large loops, since your application is only 3 iterations it shouldn't be problematic.

Comment: According to the [jax.lax.scan documentation](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.lax.scan.html): xs (~X) – the value of type [a] over which to scan along the leading axis, where [a] can be an array or any pytree (nested Python tuple/list/dict) thereof with consistent leading axis sizes. So I think tuples are accepted. NJ can be arbitrary value; it won't always be 4.

Comment: True, in which case it's equivalent to simultaneously scanning over an axis of each array in the pytree, not scanning over the pytree elements. So the original answer still stands: if you want to use `lax.scan` to scan over something, that something must be the axis of an array.